# Unable to install pocketsphinx

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am running Python 3.8.5 on Mac OS Big sur.

The issue originates from my attempt to use the python library speech_recognition.

From https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition, an example of code contains the following, which results in the RequestError, which is an import error.

```
try:
    print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio, language = 'it_IT'))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

Attempting to install the module pocketsphinx with pip, I get two large bodies of errors, but at the end of the first block there is this:

```
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
```

Any search on the internet will lead to this solution (github: https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/209, stack overflow: [ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx while trying to install pocketsphinx with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56332102/error-failed-building-wheel-for-pocketsphinx-while-trying-to-install-pocketsphi)):

```
sudo apt-get install -y python python-dev python-pip build-essential swig git libpulse-dev

pip install pocketsphinx
```

Now, it is my understanding that apt-get is not available on Mac OS X. Instead, you can use brew. But almost none of these can be installed with brew.

I tried to run:

```
brew install pocketsphinx
```

And it installed cmu-pocketsphinx, but this doesn't help me in using pocketsphinx in python.

I also tried all the instructions in the "Install development version" on https://pypi.org/project/pocketsphinx/.

I even tried modifying 2 lines of c code as per instructions here, but to no avail:
https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-precise/issues/75

Without pocketsphinx, it's impossible to use, among others, speech_recognition, so my question is how can you install pocketsphinx for python?

Comment: first error means module uses C/C++ code and it needs C/C++ compiler `gcc` for this. It may need also other files with C/C++ code or at least files `*.h`. If you see any `.h` in error message then you may have to install it. For example `Python.h` needs to install `python-dev`